# Excel VBA UserForm Scrollbar movement problem by click on Windows with multiple displays 125%

Tags: excel, vba

Folks I'm facing a problem with Excel UserForms scrollbar. The moving bar within the scrollbar is not clickable for machines with scaled display settings within Windows (usually 125% for FullHD Laptops).

Is there an common workaround that can be implemented in the UserForm settings? It can be solved by setting the Excel settings to "optimize for compatibility" or just lower the scaling to 100%. However I don't want to force the user to change his setup just to make my crap working.

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Old VB UserForms are going to become more problematic as Windows 10 evolves because MS doesn't support VBA anymore. That setting you cite is, in fact, the solution they are offering. You can set it via registry:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Options\RenderForMonitorDpi
```

> (0=optimize for compatibilty, 1=optimize for best appearance)

Comment: `because MS doesn't support VBA anymore.` Can you explain what do you mean by this statement?

Comment: @SiddharthRout, the current version of VBA is `7.1.1100` and it hasn't been updated since 2012. You can see some of the history here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications#Version_history

Comment: That doesn't mean that it is not supported anymore. It is just that it is not updated anymore. Also fromt he same link `Microsoft said that it has no plan to remove VBA from the Windows version of Office.` That is as good as supporting it...

Comment: Uhhh, no. Allowing something to exist in it's current format is not support. Support, by definition, is the closing of bugs through updates. You can "support" software through technical support but that's not the same as actually fixing problems. Seems like an odd thing to quibble about.

Comment: Well, "Support" has another definition as well. When MS doesnt support something, it asks you specifically to upgrade and not use it. Ex:  Win XP. MS hasn't said anything about not using VBA. So that is a very bold statement to make. :) `Seems like an odd thing to quibble about.` You may think it is trivial but for me it isn't. VBA is still a significant part of my work and will remain so. I keep coming across people who try to show VBA down. Your statement has no relation to the question asked (Just my opinion) Not trying to get into an unecessary debate here, I just expressed what I feel. :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout, I too use VBA every day. I don't want it to go away. I would like to see VBA, WinForms, and the VBE updated. So I want them to support VBA in my definition of the term.